# Jenkins pipelines script

Tags: git, jenkins, github, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm trying to write my first pipeline script, my idea is as following. 
I have a main branch, two of my teams will create two branches to do their projets from the main one. After their commits in the two separate branches, a job will be started to merge these two branches to the main one, after a build will be triggered.

This is my pipeline script that I have started i have not finished it yet :

```groovy
pipeline {
  agent any

  stages {
    stage ('Initialize') {
      steps {

        checkout changelog: true,
                 poll: true,
                 scm: [
                     $class: 'GitSCM',
                     branches: [[name: 'origin/master'], [name: 'origin/branch1'], [name: 'origin/branch2']],
                     doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false,
                     extensions: [
                         [
                             $class: 'PreBuildMerge',
                             options: [fastForwardMode: 'NO_FF',
                                 mergeRemote: 'https://github.com/-----/jenkins.git',
                                 mergeStrategy: 'org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.MergeCommand.Strategy',
                                 mergeTarget: 'master']
                         ]
                     ],
                     submoduleCfg: [],
                     userRemoteConfigs: [
                         [
                             credentialsId: '----------------',
                             name: 'origin',
                             url: 'https://github.com/------/jenkins.git'
                         ]
                     ]
                 ]

      }
    }

    stage ('Build') {
      steps {
        bat(/mvn clean package/)
      }
      post {
        success {
          junit 'target/surefire-reports/**/*.xml'
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This is the output:

```
Started by user admin
Running in Durability level: MAX_SURVIVABILITY
[Pipeline] node
Running on Jenkins in C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\shared-pipeline
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Initialize)
[Pipeline] checkout
  git.exe rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
  git.exe config remote.origin.url https://github.com/------/jenkins.git # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from https://github.com/------/jenkins.git
  git.exe --version # timeout=10
using GIT_ASKPASS to set credentials 
  git.exe fetch --tags --progress https://github.com/------/jenkins.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
Seen branch in repository origin/branch1
Seen branch in repository origin/branch2
Seen branch in repository origin/master
Seen 3 remote branches
git.exe show-ref --tags -d # timeout=10
Merging Revision d466248662265f20ba50d752a6ca455314c (origin/branch1) to https://github.com/-----/jenkins.git/master, UserMergeOptions{mergeRemote='https://github.com/------/jenkins.git', mergeTarget='master', mergeStrategy='org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.MergeCommand.Strategy', fastForwardMode='--no-ff'}
git.exe rev-parse "https://github.com/-------/jenkins.git/master^{commit}" # timeout=10
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Build)
Stage 'Build' skipped due to earlier failure(s)
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "git.exe rev-parse "https://github.com/--------/jenkins.git/master^{commit}"" returned status code 128:
stdout: https://github.com/--------/jenkins.git/master^{commit}

stderr: fatal: Invalid object name 'https'.

    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1996)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1964)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1960)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommand(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1597)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommand(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1609)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.revParse(CliGitAPIImpl.java:794)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitAPI.revParse(GitAPI.java:316)
    at hudson.plugins.git.extensions.impl.PreBuildMerge.decorateRevisionToBuild(PreBuildMerge.java:66)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.determineRevisionToBuild(GitSCM.java:1068)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:1161)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.scm.SCMStep.checkout(SCMStep.java:113)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.scm.SCMStep$StepExecutionImpl.run(SCMStep.java:85)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.scm.SCMStep$StepExecutionImpl.run(SCMStep.java:75)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.AbstractSynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution$1$1.call(AbstractSynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.java:47)
    at hudson.security.ACL.impersonate(ACL.java:290)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.AbstractSynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution$1.run(AbstractSynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.java:44)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Finished: FAILURE
```

Thank you in advance for your response.